# Are there any actors who appear in both versions of Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I'm looking to find out if any of the actors from the 1970's Battlestar Galactica appeared as guest stars in the 2005-2009 Series?

I've compared the IMDB list as best i can, and done some searching and didn't find any prior questions.

Comment: PS. IMDB has this "Common collaborators" search feature. https://www.imdb.com/search/name?roles=tt0407362,tt0076984

Comment: That's like a poor-man's [Bacon Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Degrees_of_Kevin_Bacon) ;-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Richard Hatch](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0368745/) played Apollo in the 1978 series, then played Tom Zarek, the political activist, in the 2004 series.

Ref: [Wikipedia - Battlestar Galactica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica)

Comment: I think for "political activist", what you meant to say was "convicted terrorist" :)

Comment: I think when you said "convicted terrorist", what you meant to say was "vice president" ;P

Comment: What I wanted was to avoid adding any ‘weight ‘ to the politics ;)

Comment: @Darkwing - Spoiler alert!

Comment: Hatch had long lobbied for a revival of the original Battlestar Galactica series, even putting together a "Second Coming" trailer in 1999.  But the Ron Moore series was essentially disconnected from Hatch's efforts.  It was nice to see Hatch get a juicy bit in the re-imagined series.